# PowerBroker Identity Services on Solaris 5.10 - Access Denied

Tags: active-directory, solaris-10, likewise-open

I was asked to investigate why when using Likewise-Open to login to Active Directory, the GIDs were not being mapped across. Logins were working fine.

I discovered that for this to work we need to install the Enterprise version. I did this over the top of the open version, and now I cannot login.

I've left and re-joined the domain but I always get `Access Denied` when logging in with an AD user (my local root account still works).

I'm lost!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having was resolved by adding the User I was trying to login with into the Default cell in Cell Manager.